# Fast collision detection in Box2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, collision-detection, box2d

Imagine there are 20 types of objects.

What fast methods exist to detect which objects collide now in Box2d?

A scan with switch/if is not fast enough.

Comment: i have used scan with if(with the tags of sprite) and it seams nice, what's the problem?

Comment: If only 20 types:   if(sprite.tag == kTag1) { ...}  if(sprite.tag == kTag2) {...} .........if (sprite.tag = ktag20) {...}  20 times if(sprite.tag == kTagX)!  And to reach up to kTag20 needed to pass previous 19 "if".

Answer (score 2):

The best way to keep an updated list of which objects are currently colliding with each other is to use the BeginContact/EndContact events to update the list - typically each object would store such a list so it can access whatever it's touching efficiently. If you really think it's a problem to check the tags of the other objects in this list, you could have more than one list, eg. you could keep all touching objects of kTag1 in a list by themselves.